# Why different records in the model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have this abstract models.

```
class Abstract_Detail(models.Model):
""" Abstract models for detail in subassembly """

name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
mark = models.CharField(max_length=50)

weight_end = models.FloatField(blank=True,
              null=True, default=0)

class Meta:
    abstract = True
    unique_together = ('name', 'makr')
```

And Details model.

```
class Detail(Abstract_Detail):
""" Detail """

auto_area = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0.0)
size_workpiece = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
weight = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
product = models.ManyToManyField(Products, through='Structure_production')
subassembly = models.ManyToManyField(Subassembly, through='Structure_production')
material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             null=True, blank=True)
assortament = models.ForeignKey(Sortment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                null=True, blank=True)

class Meta():
    unique_together = ('name', 'makr')
```

What is the problem: in some cases, when you change weight_end in admin  Detail, when executing the below code, a new record is created with a combination of the name and mark, which is already in the model.

```
    detail, sost = Detail.objects.get_or_create(
    name=name, makr=makr,
    defaults={'size_workpiece': size,
              'material': material,
              'assortament': sortament})
```

Is there an explanation? Read the documentation fully, the answer is not found.

Comment: is `mark` in `Abstract_Detail` supposed to be typo

Comment: Its strange when you are using `unique_together = ('name', 'makr')` it cannot create another duplicate